# Is there a way to automatically remove old trace Zipkin entries in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, data-cleaning, zipkin

This is specifically for Zipkin's Cassandra storage connector.

Is there a way of automatically removing old traces?

I've search on the Web but I didn't find information about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per their docs,

- data has 7 days TTL
- indexes has 3 days TTL

Docs:

- https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin/tree/master/zipkin-storage/cassandra#time-to_live
- https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin/blob/master/zipkin-server/README.md#cassandra-storage